# Date time picker in bootstrap modal, scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I have a problem when scrolling in bootstrap modal with the date time picker plugin. (not date picker).

When I am scrolling in modal, the date box stays fixed page, but normally it shouldn't do that

Where is a lot solutions for bootstrap-datepicker, but I use bootstrap-datetimepicker , and I can't find a solution for it, or maybe I can't find it?

Comment: Have you a fiddl? Or you could just give the datetimepicker a class, which position isnt fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: relative;` to the parent container.

Answer (score 0):

I also had encountered the same problem, and my date time picker default is displayed below the input box, the separation of the input box and date time picker plug when slide the modal, the I can let the date time picker plug default display on the input box above, so my javascript code is:

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    #this is other option
    ...
    pickerPosition: 'top-right',
});
```